# How to change the size of the thermal printer font?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, printing

Here his my code to print using thermal printer TP50 oxhoo:

```
runas /user:Administrator cd c:/
ECHO myText to print >> commande
print /D:"\\%COMPUTERNAME%\tp50" commande
del commande
```

I don't now how to change the size of the font. Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi Xavier, welcome to Stack Overflow. 
What have you tried so far that did not work out? You will get more helpful answers if you show that you have already tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Hi @Kaadzia, I tried to insert escape character like : ESC E is the command to select a bold font (ref : http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf) but nothing append ..

Comment: How exactly are you sending the esc? You know this is an invisible control character ASCII 0x1B, right?

Comment: @tripleee I add it right in front of my line : ECHO \033P COMMANDE 2 >> commande , I don't no how it's work , can you explain me please ?

Comment: I also try : echo -e '\033[1mYOUR_STRING\033[0m' >> commande

Comment: I think it's because the Windows console does not support ANSI escape sequences :/

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944154/how-do-i-send-dos-commands-to-my-receipt-printer-via-com1), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624134/how-to-use-ms-dos-commands-to-cut-paper-using-esc-pos-commands)